# Change dimensions of plot MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, neural-network, matlab-figure, som

I'm trying to visualize SOM neural network. There is a `plotsom` function for this. It works but it stretches the plot through one dimension:

original plot:
[image]

and different views (X-Y ; X-Z and Y-Z):
[image]

I don't understand how to make it's axis fairly evenly disturbed. My code:
(originally `A == net.IW{1,1}` and `B = net.layers{1}.distances`)

```
A =  

1.0e+04 *

0.1659    0.0736    1.7223
0.1460    0.0772    1.2072
0.1207    0.0747    1.4661
0.1007    0.0783    0.9510
0.1439    0.0895    1.4653
0.1239    0.0930    0.9502
0.0987    0.0905    1.2091
0.0787    0.0941    0.6941

B = 

 0     1     1     2     1     2     2     3
 1     0     1     1     1     1     2     2
 1     1     0     1     1     2     1     2
 2     1     1     0     2     1     1     1
 1     1     1     2     0     1     1     2
 2     1     2     1     1     0     1     1
 2     2     1     1     1     1     0     1
 3     2     2     1     2     1     1     0


plotsom(A,B)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plot is using `axis equal` to ensure that the scaling on each axis is the same. If you want to disable this, you can call [`axis normal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#inputarg_style) after plotting which will changes the scaling of each axis to best fit the data.

```
plotsom(A,B);
axis normal
```

[image]

Comment: That's simple and perfect! Thank you for answer and for editing my title!